# What am I doing wrong here? (Python 3) (Beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to create a program that lets the user send words to the program and it will add them to a list then make the list a string and print it.

```
class joinString():

    op_list = []    # this is what i was told to do to initialize a list

    def init(self):    # idk what this is used for to be honest
        print("Hello")

    def main(self):

        string_in = ""    # string input
        print("Enter strings, to stop enter a '0'")
        while string_in != '0':    #while loop checks if string equals '0', stop
            string_in = input("String: ")    #asks user for inputs
            joinString().op_list.append(string_in)
        final_string = ''.join(joinString().op_list)    # makes final string 
        print("Final Product: " + final_string)    # prints final string

if __name__ == "__main__":    #idk what a name is
    test = joinString()
    test.main()

# I took AP computer science A (coding in java) and scored pretty well but I 
# didn't know where to go from there so I'm trying to learn java.
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting/indentation of your code here so that it is identical to how it appears in the file on your computer.  What about this code isn't working?

Comment: "I took AP computer science A (coding in java) and scored pretty well but I didn't know where to go from there so I'm trying to learn java." - then why are you writing Python?

Answer (score 1):

In your `main` you're using `joinString()` when you should be using `self`. A larger issue is that you're writing Java style code in Python. Here's a more *Pythonic* solution to your problem:

```
print('Type a word then hit enter. Leave blank to exit.')
words = []
while True:
    word = input('Word: ')
    if not word:
        break
    words.append(word)
print(*words)
```

First we print out a message telling the user how to use the program. We use the empty string to indicate that the users wants to exit.

```
print('Type a word then hit enter. Leave blank to exit.')
```

Then we create an empty list, `words`, to store the user's input.

```
words = []
```

Next, we enter an infinity loop (don't worry we'll `break` out of it later).

```
while True:
```

We ask the user to enter a word and store it in `word`.

```
    word = input('Word: ')
```

In Python, the empty string is false. So we check if the user entered nothing.

```
    if not word:
```

If they enter nothing, we break out of the infinite loop.

```
        break
```

If they entered something, we add the word they entered to the end of `words` and loop back around.

```
    words.append(word)
```

Be default, `print()` puts a space between each object it prints. So, we use the `*` operate to pass each element of `words` as an argument to `print()`. This causes each word to be printed with a space between them.

```
print(*words)
```

Hope that helps you learn Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` method should refer to the instance with `self` rather than instantiating another instance of `joinString` with `joinString()`.

Replace:

```
joinString().op_list.append(string_in)
```

with:

```
self.op_list.append(string_in)
```

and replace:

```
final_string = ''.join(joinString().op_list)
```

with:

```
final_string = ''.join(self.op_list)
```

Also, the `init` method should be spelled `__init__`, and is used to initialize the object when it's being instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

```
class joinString():

op_list = []  

def main(self):

    string_in = ""    # string input
    print("Enter strings, to stop enter a '0'")
    while True:    
        string_in = input("String: ")    #asks user for inputs
        if string_in == '0':
            break
        joinString().op_list.append(string_in)
    final_string = ''.join(joinString().op_list)    # makes final string
    print("Final Product: " + final_string)    # prints final string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = joinString()
    test.main()
```

This code is working on my end. I changed your while condition because it was adding 0 to the final string